# Not understanding where 404 error is comming from

Tags: node.js

I have an Express route that I am unable to get working. I am using postman to test the HTTP request and I just can't seem to get the code to work. If anyone has suggestions, or how to go about fixing this, i.e thought process, that would be helpful.

```
router.put('/users', function(req, res) {
    //use authorization
    let user = getUserIdFromToken(req.get('Authorization'));

    if (typeof(req.body) !== 'string') {
      // 400: Bad request.
      res.status(400).end();
      return;
    }
    var body = req.body;
    if(body.firstName!==null) user.firstName = body.firstName;
    if(body.lastName!==null) user.lastName = body.lastName;
    if(body.displayName!==null) user.displayName = body.displayName;
    if(body.userEmail!==null) user.userEmail = body.userEmail;

    writeDocument('users', user);
    res.send();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: 404 means your web server can't route to a resource according to the requested URL (i.e. "page not found"). The question is meaningless unless you tell us the URL you tried to access, and where the app is mounted.